# Appending csv values to list based on condition using pandas

Tags: python, list, pandas, function

I was trying to open a csv file `panda_try.csv`. What i want to do is to compare the elements in the first two columns from the file and check if they are equal. If they are equal, I want to append it in a list called `selfloop_appender` and then calculate the length of list. But when i try to `print (selfloop_appender)', i donot get any output and error. Any help will be great.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('/home/venkat/Desktop/panda_try.csv')
xy_data = df.iloc[:,0:2]

def self_loops(xy_data):
    selfloop_appender = []
    for i,j in xy_data:
        if i == j:
            selfloop_appender.append([i,j])
            print("the number of self_loops are:") + len(str(selfloop_appender))

    return selfloop_appender
self_loops(xy_data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `nunique`, if it equal to 1 , mean i=j.

```
xy_data[xy_data.nunique(1)==1].iloc[:,1].tolist()
```

Update

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'B':[1,2,6]})
df.nunique(1)
Out[440]: 
0    1
1    1
2    2
dtype: int64
```

If return 1 means A=B

Then we using `eq`(equal to `==`) to slice the row we need

```
df[df.nunique(1).eq(1)]
Out[442]: 
   A  B
0  1  1
1  2  2
df[df.nunique(1).eq(1)].iloc[:,1]
Out[443]: 
0    1
1    2
Name: B, dtype: int64
df[df.nunique(1).eq(1)].iloc[:,1].tolist()
Out[444]: [1, 2]
```

Comment: I am not able to understand, can u make the edit in the code?